# std::set<pair<int,int> > -- find only using pair<>::first as the key

Tags: c++, find, set

So I'm having a Red Black Tree containing pairs of `int`, and when i call `.find(x)` function it will search for `x` (both first and second), but i want to make it ignore the second value, and look only for the first value. How can i do that?

Comment: You've effectively described `std::map<int,int>`

Comment: If the first element of a pair has same elemnts, consider multimap instead of map

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not possible. But for your limited case of pair of `int`s you can fake it using `upper_bound()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    using key_type = std::pair<int, int>;
    std::set<key_type> s { {1, -1}, {1, 3}, {2, 10}, {3, 42} };
    auto it = s.upper_bound (key_type (2, std::numeric_limits<int>::min ()));
    std::cout << "(" << it->first << "; " << it->second << ")\n";
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f780d510fad3bd4a)

Comment: Don't worry, i just found a nice way.

Comment: @VladPotra - You didn't share that nice way - how rude :)

Comment: It's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
auto fn = [](const pair<int, int>&a, const pair <int, int>&b) {
  return a.first < b.first;
};
set<pair<int, int>, decltype(fn)> my_set(fn);
```

my_set is now a set that uses only `pair.first` as the key

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto fn = [](const pair<int, int>&a, const pair <int, int>&b) {
      return a.first < b.first;
    };
    set<pair<int, int>, decltype(fn)> my_set(fn);
    
    my_set.insert({1, 123});
    my_set.insert({4, 456});
    my_set.insert({7, 789});
    
    auto iter = my_set.find({4, 0});
    if (iter != my_set.end()) {
      cout << "first: " << iter->first << ", second: " << iter->second << "\n";
    } else {
      cout << "not found\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
first: 4, second: 456
```

change `my_set` to just `set<pair<int, int>> my_set;` and it will print `not found`

Of course, keying only on `first` is arguably a `map<int, int>` so why not just do that?